# How to render blade component with JS?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

So, I have blade component, called answerInput. It has incoming parameters and some logic inside.
When I'm rendering it as usual - by manually adding tag into DOM tree, everything works fine:

```
<x-answer-input type="radio"></x-answer-input>
```

And after render, I get following code:

```
<div class="mb-4 row">
    <div class="group col">
        <label for="name" class="form-label">Answer name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name[]">
    </div>
    <input type="radio" class="col input">
</div>
```

But I need to add this component dynamically, using JS function:

```
        let addAnswer = () => {
            let answer = document.createElement("x-answer-input");
            answer.setAttribute('type', getParamValue());
            answers.appendChild(answer);
        }
```

Function adds element to the DOM tree, but it doesn't seem to be processed by Blade, because finally, there still only the template tag in document.

```
<x-answer-input type="radio"></x-answer-input>
```

Comment: Blade components are processed serverside. JavaScript runs clientside. You can't run serverside code on the clientside. Maybe you should consider using a client-side MVVM (e.g. Vue or React) to better manage your views clientside

Comment: You might consider using a solution like [Livewire](https://laravel-livewire.com/)